# Implementing remove characters in C

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to implement `char* removeChars(char* str, char* remove)` in `C`

However if I pass in `"Battle of the Vowels"` and `"aeiou"`, I get `"Bttlftwl"` returned.
Any helps pointing out the bug(s) in my code would be appreciated!  Preparing for upcoming interviews!  Note that this is a question from Programming Interviews Exposed, the provided solution is in C#, I'm trying to implement a C version as well for practice.

```
char* removeCharacters(char* string, char* toRemove)
{
    int flags[128];
    while(*toRemove)
    {
        flags[*toRemove] = 1;
        toRemove++;
    }
    char* head = string;
    char* src = string;
    char* dest = string;
    while(*string)
    {
        if (!flags[*string])
        {
            *dest = *src;
            dest++;
        }
        src++;
        string++;
    }
    *dest = NULL;
    return head;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one major problem with your code is that you don't initialize all of `flags`, meaning parts (or even most) of the array will contain indeterminable values. Local variables, including arrays, are not initialized. You have to do it yourself.

A very simple way of doing it is to do

```
int flags[128] = { 0 };
```

as that will initialize all values to zero.

Comment: Second. This is probably it.